# how to move maven,spring boot,sql projects from one drive to another

Tags: partitioning, java, 20.04, mysql, eclipse

I have two disks on my laptop after a recent ROM upgrade.
I have all my java projects(used maven, spring boot and MySql) running on 128g disk(Ubuntu 20.04) and I installed Ubuntu on the new disk too and I want to run my projects here.
I copied the eclipse workspace and .M2 and .eclipse folders but it ends up with errors again.
Can somebody give an idea of all the folders I need to move to my 512g disk for this ?
I use jdk11 in the new disk and old disk uses 1.8.0_252.
Currently, I dual boot for two disks with 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should just copy the eclipse-workspace folder.

Then install Eclipse and MySQL on your new Ubuntu.

First time you open Eclipse, it will prompt you to either use the default Eclipse workspace or a custom one. You can point to the workspace you have copied.

I you have launched Eclipse already, you can change the default workspace from the File > Switch Workspace menu:

[image: Eclipse File menu]

With this, you should already be able to find your projects at the state you left them on the other drive.

Then, you will have to re-configure your environment to get your projects running : recreate the databases, the DB user(s), the server if any (Tomcat, Jetty... But SpringBoot comes with one embedded already, does it ?), server users, ensure that the config is in line with your config files, ensure that the environment variables are set...

I hope this helps, but if it doesn't, may I suggest you to edit your post and add some details about the errors you get ?